# What is the relation of these 3 models: user, birthday, label?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a birthday calendar app. It will have the following models:
- Django's user model
- Birthday
- Label (i.e. friends, family)

I'm not sure how to model the Label class. The user should have the ability to create a new Label object which can then be used when creating a Birthday object.
The user should also be able to filter Birthday's based on the Label.

How would you model these relationships in a db?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Birthday(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    day = models.DateField()

class Label(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Label(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=25)



class Birthday(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    day = models.DateField()
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Use Label as the Foreignkey of Birthday. So you will know which birthday is related to which Label.

You can then filter out Birthday based on label like this.

```
Birthday.objects.filter(label__id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you can add `Label` as [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) Field in Birthday Model. In that way, you can assign this label/labels to `Birthday`. You can have multiple label to a birthday, and one label can have multiple birthdays. So it will be like this:

```
class Birthday(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    day = models.DateField()
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Label)
```

Usage:

```
birthday = Birthday.objects.create(...)
label = Label.objects.create(...)
b.labels.add(label)
Birthday.objects.filter(labels=label)
```